# How best to handle Constraint Violations in Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

What is considered the best/most correct way to handle a Constraint Violation in Spring JDBC?

As a real example. I've got a `users` table that contains, amongst other things, columns of `url_slug` and `email`. Both of these are UNIQUE. When creating a new record, or updating an existing record, if I try to make one record contain a duplicate value of another record in this table I want to return a sensible error back to the caller.

The only options I can think of are both flawed. I'm doing this in Postgres 10, using Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in case that matters at all.

#### Check the data before doing the INSERT/UPDATE.

This will involve an extra query on every Insert/Update call, and has a race condition that means it might still not catch it. i.e.

1. Thread 1 starts transaction
2. Thread 2 starts transaction
3. Thread 1 queries data
4. Thread 2 queries data
5. Thread 1 does update
6. Thread 2 does update
7. Thread 1 does commit
8. Thread 2 does commit <-- Constraint Violation, even though at #4 the data was fine

#### Handle the `DuplicateKeyException`.

The problem here is that it's not thrown until the Transaction is committed, at which point it might well be unclear exactly which SQL call failed, which constraint failed, or anything else like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" way to handle these kind of exceptions, except putting it into a try catch block and propagate back the error message to the user.

Of course in your example the problem is that you most probably don't want to use `Serializable` isolation level which essentially executes every transaction one-by-one, making sure that this cannot happen. Another way would be to lock the table for the entire transaction, but I wouldn't advise that either.

Simply put your transactional call into a try-catch block and handle it as you want.

Comment: Is there a sane way to get the actual violations out of the exception? I'd like to be able to present to the user exactly what the problem is, rather than an abstract "something went wrong" message.

Comment: I don't have a ready to go example at the moment but if you are getting a general DataAccessException from Spring, then I think you can use the getRootCause method on that to obtain the original exception.

Comment: I did try digging through it earlier and there's nothing in the exception tree that gives you the constraint name, column name, or anything like that except for the message, which is in database terms not API terms, plus exposes internal details...

Comment: If you couldn't find anything which you can use, you have to go with a general error message like "Try again" or something.